# JFace MessageDialog, message string contains '&' char; '&' not displayed

Tags: jface, ampersand, messagedialog

I am trying to use JFace Messagedialog.openInformation dialog, and my message string contains an ampersand '&' character.  The ampersand is not displayed when the dialog is opened.  Through trial and error, I have found that if I double the ampersand to && in the string, then it will display.

Escaping the & within the string has no effect.

Obviously, this is not the case if I write the string to system.out; so it is not a problem with String itself.

I am looking for some documentation on why this occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LegacyActionTools.escapeMnemonics(message)` to escape the mnemonics in the situation when they should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

& is used to identify mnemonic accelerators for controls ... so it's possible that the text you are passing to the `MessageDialog.openInformation` method is being parsed by the same logic.

I haven't dug into the SWT code much, but I can't find a specific place where it is handling the '&' character, so it might be happening at the OS level.